# Trouble making an Activator listener (With theos)

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, activator, tweak

I have recently started learning how to develop tweaks with theos, hook into apps etc. I wanted to make an Activator listener that simply speaks out Test. Speak out test not log, yes I know.

I recently found this command line utility on Cydia named **speak** which allowed my device to speak through terminal. I found an Activator template on AppleNerd's repo on Github and it worked out pretty well until the compiling part came. I used the system(speak test); where I wrote the code like this:

```objc
#import "libactivator.h"
@interface Testivator : NSObject<LAListener> 
{} 
@end

@implementation Testivator

-(void)activator:(LAActivator *)activator receiveEvent:(LAEvent *)event {
   system("speak Test");
}

+(void)load {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [[LAActivator sharedInstance] registerListener:[self new] forName:@"um"];
    [p release];
}
@end
```

And the makefile looks like this:

```bsh
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = Testivator
Testivator_FILES = Listener.xm
Testivator_LDFLAGS = -lactivator

include /var/theos/makefiles/tweak.mk
```

I am using RPetrich's latest activator header but when I try to compile it tells me that the library could not be found. Like this:

> ld: Library not found for -lactivator

Why won't this compile?

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED IT!!! I put the libactivator.dylib from usr/lib/ to var/theos/lib/ (opt/theos/ on Mac) and then tried to compile it, voila! I could compile it. Note one more thing, that if you are creating an activator listener make a plist like with tweaks, that filters springboard (depending on your tweak) and add necessary frameworks to your makefile too!